# Testing Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am messing around with Java 8 lambda and I was trying to do the following but apparently I am doing something very wrong. I have an array of string `String [] q` and I was trying to call a static method that returns a set of `Node` objects for each element in the array. 
Here is what I wrote:

```
Set<Set<Node>> sets = Arrays.asList(q).stream().forEach(InMemoryGraph::getAllPredicates);
```

`getAllPredicates` is a method that accepts a String as an argument and returns a `Set<Node>`
Do I need to use `java.util.function`? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, `getAllPredicates` is a static method, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:

- you have an array which you want to stream: `Arrays.stream(q)`
- then you want to map each string to a set of node: `.map(InMemoryGraph::getAllPredicates)`
- and collect those sets in a set: `.collect(toSet());`

in one go:

```
Set<Set<Node>> sets = Arrays.stream(q) //a Stream<String>
                       .map(InMemoryGraph::getAllPredicates) // a Stream<Set<Node>>
                       .collect(toSet()); // a Set<Set<Node>>
```

Note: you need a static import of `Collectors.toSet`.

Comment: Somehow the compiler doesn't like `InMemoryGraph::getAllPredicates`, it keeps asking to define a local variable or a field with the name `InMemoryGraph`, which is the name of the class. `getAllPredicates` is a public static method in that class. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to import the class maybe?

Comment: You could also try the equivalent lambda: `.map(s -> InMemoryGraph.getAllPredicates(s))` and see what message you get. Can you confirm that the method signature is `public static Set<Node> getAllPredicates(String s)`?

Comment: this line is in another static method within the same class. I used `s -> InMemoryGraph.getAllPredicates(s)` as well it says create a local variable called `s`!!

Comment: @Arsham are you sure you are compiling for Java 8 (and not Java 7)? Have you managed to create a simple program with a lambda?

Comment: That was caused by an IDE (eclipse) issue, apparently you have to download a support package for eclipse from marketplace to support Java 8. Even though I had JDK 1.8, eclipse was still compiling for Java 7. Thanks for the help.